# Comparing Primitives and References

Tags: java

I am little confused about some concepts in Primitive and Referenced data types ... I know the difference, but when i tried out this code, the output is unexpected!

```
class Learn{

public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    int a = 5;
    int b = 6;
    int c = 5;
    
    System.out.println(a);
    System.out.println(b);
    System.out.println(c);
    
    if (a == c)
        System.out.println("PE");
    
    if (b != c)
        System.out.println("PNE");
    
    System.out.println("========");
    
    Integer x = new Integer(5);
    Integer y = new Integer(6);
    Integer z = new Integer(5);
    
    System.out.println(x);
    System.out.println(y);
    System.out.println(z);
    
    if (x == z)
        System.out.println("RE");
    
    if (y != z)
        System.out.println("RNE");
}
}
```

and that is the output

> 5
>
> 6
>
> 5
>
> PE
>
> PNE
>
> ========
>
> 5
>
> 6
>
> 5
>
> RNE

So why `RE` is not written to STDOUT like `RNE`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Integer x = new Integer(5);
Integer y = new Integer(6);
Integer z = new Integer(5);
```

`x` and `z` refer to different `Integer` objects (since each type you use the `new` keyword, you are creating a unique object). Therefore `x==z` is false. `x.equals(z)` would return true, since both objects contain the same numeric value.

Answer (score 0):

Because when you are comparing x and z, you are actually comparing the Objects, not the the value they contain.

Answer (score 0):

`x` and `z` refer to different `Integer` objects. When you compare `x == y`, you are comparing object references.

On the other hand,  `a`, `b`, `c` are value types, so when you compare `a == c`, then their values will be compared.